# Efficient way to check for same condition on multiple columns Hive

Tags: hive

I am trying to run a Hive query which checks for the same criteria across multiple columns

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE col_1 NOT IN ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd') OR col_1 IS NULL
AND col_2 NOT IN ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd') OR col_2 IS NULL
AND col_3 NOT IN ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd') OR col_3 IS NULL
AND col_4 NOT IN ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd') OR col_4 IS NULL;
```

Is there a way to represent this in a more compact/efficient manner since the operations are exactly the same on all columns?